# How to make gcp schedule execute tasks at a specific time every hour?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, schedule

How to set schedule as "every 1 minutes from every hours from HH:10 to HH:15"?
I want the task to be executed at a specific time every hour, but gcp doesn't seem to support it.

In a nutshell,I want to execute the task 5 times per hour.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref

"every 1 minutes from every hours from HH:10 to HH:15" not working.

Comment: What does `HH:10 to HH:15` mean? Are you trying to specify any hours?

Comment: In a nutshell,I want to execute the task 5 times per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"5 times per hour"* would essentially mean every 12 minutes. Try:

```
schedule: every 12 minutes
```

If you are using Cloud Scheduler, you can specify a cron:

```
*/12 * * * *
```

---

For running its every `11-15th` every hour being 10-15 hours, try using the cron:

```
11-15 10-15 * * *
```

Comment: I want the task to execute at a specific time. 
ex: 
13:11, 13:12, 13:13, 13:14, 13:15, 
14:11, 14:12, 14:13, 14:14, 14:15
…
…..

Comment: @Peter it might be easier to use Cloud Scheduler with a cron as in my updated answer